# How to stop paint deterioration of inner side of roof

Tags: energy-management

Our concrete  roof paint deteriorates from inner side, probably due to presence of moisture in concrete, & it results in poor luck of roof .. Please guide me , how to stop paint deterioration ?

Note : walls under the roof are made of bricks & mud mortar ...

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! I'm not sure this is the most appropriate stackexchange website to ask this question. [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) may be a better choice. Or are you looking explicitly for a solution with low environmental impact?

Comment: He used the tag "energy-management" so he is likely interested in a low impact solution.

@zeshan Is there an attic and the paint is just being used to seal the concrete roof, or is the "inner side" of your roof the same as the ceiling?

Answer (score 3):

Moss takes a while to grow, but when it fills in it makes a beautiful interior or exterior wall covering. If the concrete has moisture that will actually help the moss grow without need of misting like you would on a dry surface.

Check out [these pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=moss+wall&source=lnms&tbm=isch) to get some ideas.

Here is a guide to [growing moss](http://www.mossandstonegardens.com/blog/how-to-grow-moss/). It focuses more on lawns, but the ideas are just as applicable to walls and ceilings.

If molds are an issue grow lichen first before the moss. Lichens are a multi-species organism composed of a moss like plant and a fungi. The fungal aspect of the Lichen will compete against other fungi (like black mold). If mold is already present you may need to sterilize the concrete somehow (e.g. Bleach or Rubbing Alcohol).

If moss isn't your thing, consider striping the current paint with a sand blaster, then mixing your choice of latex paint with an acrylic cement admixture and some portland cement and water to make a thin slurry that can be painted or troweled onto the ceiling. That will at least last **much** longer than a normal paint job.

Another option, is like THelper says in his comment to this answer, you might be better off finding out why the concrete gets wet and fixing that problem instead.

Comment: Moss may cover up the moisture in the concrete, but it doesn't solve the problem. Molds may start to grow as well which can lead to health problems if it is growing inside your house (not sure if this is the case, the OP didn't specify). I think the OP may be better off finding out why the concrete is moist and fix that.

Comment: If molds are an issue grow lichen first before the moss. Lichens are a multi-species organism composed of a moss like plant and a fungi. The fungal aspect of the Lichen will compete against other fungi (like black mold). If mold is already present you may need to sterilize the concrete somehow (e.g. Bleach or Rubbing Alcohol).